# Cloud functions - Save data with loop

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to set an object on Firebase database realtime by looping a list.
For example, I have list of Objects. I want to run over that list and each loop save on database realtime the object.
This is the code:

```
  if(feedVideosList.length > 0){
       feedVideosList.forEach(video =>{
         return admin.database().ref('/userFeed/${userUID}/').set(video);
     }).catch(error =>{
      console.log("Error user feed:  ",error);
    });
  }else{
    console.log("Problem with the videos list:  ",error);
  }
```

I'm pretty sure that this code is wrong and thats not the way I should write it.
Like i said, what I'm trying to do is to run over a list and save each time the data on spasific node.
The question is how should i do that, whats the right way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running this code in Cloud Functions, my best guess is that you want the Cloud Function to terminate after all writes to the database are completed. You can use `Promise.all()` for that:

```
  if(feedVideosList.length > 0){
    let promises = []
     feedVideosList.forEach(video =>{
       promises.push(admin.database().ref('/userFeed/${userUID}/').set(video));
     })
     return Promise.all(promises).catch(error =>{
      console.log("Error user feed:  ",error);
    });
  }else{
    console.log("Problem with the videos list:  ",error);
  }
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed